# Lack of access to classes in Back Tick

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
function Home() {
  let displayCards = Galeyre.map((item) => {
    return `
        <div class="card_container">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="face-side">
                    <alt="Question mark">
                </div>
                <div class="back-side">
                    <alt="${item.name} flag icon">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`;
  }).join("");
```

No matter what I did, I can't style the element classes in backtick in the css section, how can I fix this problem please?

Comment: Why would you return a `string` containing HTML in React?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you meant
The problem is that I can't access the classes that I used in backtick in the css section, that is, I style it, but it doesn't apply.

Comment: The comments are pointing out that your use of back-ticks to return a string is the problem. @قدافلح. That's not how React works. It's _is_ how some templating languages like [`htm`](https://github.com/developit/htm) work, or if you're using native JS to create markup (but _not_ in React) but you don't appear to be doing that. Why not just return the JSX?

Comment: Does it mean that it is not possible to access the classes in Bektik?

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do @قدافلح. Your question doesn't contain any React but your tags say you are. You appear to be creating an HTML string using back-ticks (which is fine) but, as one of the deleted comments pointed, out there are no `alt` elements, so it's very unclear to us what it is you're asking. Is this question about React or are you trying to do something else? Why do you think `<alt>` will work? Did you mean `<img alt="${item.name}" class="flag icon">` perhaps?

Comment: I am coding with react  and I want to use this amount of elements from html, but the classes I gave to the elements do not accept styles in css !!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: User error: you should be using JSX and not string-like HTML markup.

Comment: @قدافلح welcome to SO. It's great to have you utilize the platform. In this case there is some confusion because it looks like your code sample is vanilla JS. But, you tagged your question with 'reactjs' and you mention that you are coding React, but you are not. Using vanilla function components is fine, but that's different from actually using React, the UI library that wraps around JS. If it's possible to get some clarification on these points, then the response might be more fruitful.

Comment: im wille select classes in codes html, but in css fall `style.css` styles which for classes select are not applied !

Answer (score 2):

I suggest, *before you do anything* you go and read the [documentation on how to get started](https://react.dev/). In summary: React is a UI library based on *state*, and the components that you build (generally in JSX) are *reactive* to that state.

While you're generally heading in the right direction React doesn't use back-ticks to create HTML strings - all of that is dealt with as part of the library. You just need to learn the syntax, how state works, and how to organise your components so they respond to that state.

---

This documented example based on your code should help you out.

```js
const { useState } = React;

// Your Home component - we're passing in the deck // of cards through its props
function Home({ deck }) {
  
  // We set up some state using that deck
  const [cards, setCards] = useState(deck);
  
  // A function that we pass down to our Card component
  // It takes the id from the clicked card's dataset
  // and then updates the cards state based on that id, to and from `visible`
  function handleClick(e) {
    const card = e.target.closest('.card');
    if (card) {
      const { dataset: { id } } = card;
      setCards(prev => {
        return prev.map(card => {
          if (card.id === Number(id)) {
            return { ...card, visible: !card.visible };
          }
          return card;
        });
      });
    }
  }
  
  // The Home component `maps` over the cards array
  // in state and returns a Card component for each card. It also passes down a reference to the `handleClick` function
  // that each card can use when it's clicked
  return (
    <main>
      {cards.map(card => {
        return (
          <Card
            key={card.id}
            card={card}
            handleClick={handleClick}
          />
        );
      })}
    </main>
  );
}

// The card component accepts the card data, and the
// `handleClick` function in its props
function Card({ card, handleClick }) {

  // We destructure the id, name, and visible boolean
  // from the card data
  const { id, symbol, visible } = card;
  
  // And we define the HTML of the card
  // with classes (note: className, not class) that
  // respond to the changes in state
  return (
    <div
      data-id={card.id}
      className="card"
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
      <div className={`face ${visible && 'hidden'}`}>
        ?
      </div>
      <div className={`face ${!visible && 'hidden'}`}>
        {card.symbol}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

// Our deck definition - note the inclusion of the
// `visible` property - which defines whether a card // is visible (back-facing) or not visible (front-facing) 
const deck = [
  { id: 1, symbol: '♠', visible: false },
  { id: 2, symbol: '♥', visible: false },
  { id: 3, symbol: '♦', visible: false },
  { id: 4, symbol: '♣', visible: false }
];

const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);

// We pass the deck into the Home component in
// its props
root.render(<Home deck={deck} />);
```

```css
.card { width: 75px; height: 100px; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 2rem; }
.card:hover { cursor: pointer; background-color: lightyellow;}
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```